# OpenVPN, Masquerade connection freeze

Tags: linux, iptables, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN Client connected to a remote OpenVPN Server. And i also use NAT(Masquerade) so the LAN behind my client can access the LAN behind my server.

```
----------------       ----------------       ---------------       ------------------
| Client LAN   |  <--> |OpenVPN Client|  <--> |OpenVPN Server| <--> |   Server Lan   |
|192.168.1.0/24|       |  10.9.0.82   |       |   10.9.0.1   |      |  172.31.0.0/20 |  
----------------       ----------------       ----------------       -----------------
```

Mascarade: iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE

Everything works fine (most of the time).

When i do certain operations, i believe it to when i send large packets. The connection freeze.

Example: if i open FileZilla in the Client LAN and connect to a server (in the Lan Server), over SSH. It works, i can navigate, see and transfer small files, but if the file is large (> 20kb) it freeze.

First i thought it could be a MTU issue or something, i tried several things (mssfix, fragment, ...) none of them worked.

But here is the catch, if i connect to the OpenVPN Server (over SSH) and try to transfer a file for example. It works if i connect to the IP 10.9.0.1, but it freeze if i use the 172.*.

Since both are the same server, just different IPs because of the interfaces and travel through the same path, i don't think anymore it could be a MTU issue.

I also thought it could be something to do with TSO or LRO. Since i monitored the packets (with Wireshark) on the OpenVPN Client node, and it showed some packets larger than the MTU.
I thought the OS could be creating a large packet and OpenVPN not handling it properly. But it also did not work.

In the packet trace, i could also see a lot of "TCP Previous Segment Not Captured" and "TCP Acked unseen segment". So the packet is sent, there's no acknowledge. it keep trying to send, until the TCP Window is full, it re transmit (i think, from my analysis)...

And not I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My analysis was wrong. It have nothing to do with OpenVPN, Masquerade, ...

In my Client LAN, there was a pfSense with asymmetric routing.

After the State Timeout (TCP Opening), pfSense was killing the state, since there was no "answer" as it was routed from another path, making the connection freeze.

I changed network topology to make the routing symmetric and it worked.